# iOS Facebook app 5.0+ - Which cells/sections, views, components and so on is used to display the wall itself?

Tags: ios, facebook, uitableview, facebook-wall

I was wondering how the new iOS Facebook app has implemented their cells:

[image: Facebook app 5.0]

Different squares with some content inside depending on which type of information. Which components, views and so on - do you think is used?

And the tableview, is it cells or grouped sections?

Which keywords should I be looking for - to make a similar timeline-wall?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay doesnt matter. Found out I could create a viewcontroller containing tableview with grouped sections and all smaller uiviews I wanted.